# Sample-and-hold circuit that samples the difference but uses a single-ended opmap

Tags: operational-amplifier, sample-and-hold

The circuit below shows two things:

1. How to sample a single-ended voltage into a capacitor.
2. How, using a buffer, the voltage can be read by the next stage without affecting the voltage stored in the capacitor.

I would like to be able to do the same thing but instead of a single-ended input voltage (as shown below), I want to store the differential input voltage in the capacitor. How can I do this with single opamp that has 1 output (instead of fully-differential opamps).

EDIT: Image taken from **CMOS: Circuit Design, Layout, and Simulation** by R. Jacob Baker.

[image]

Comment: Is this a follow-on to [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/696077/11683)? If so, you should probably add the information there -- and explain why the existing suggestions don't work.